# Arduino I2C bus fails when one slave is powered down

Tags: arduino, avr, i2c

I have a set of Arduino Nano units where one is I2C master broadcasting messages to a number of slaves. It works perfectly fine when they are all powered on.

The Arduino units are all interconnected with wires between A4 (SDA), A5 (SCL) and GND. All of them have separate 5V lines. I have tried with internal pullups (as configured by the Wire lib) and by external 4.7k resistors.

The problem is when I cut the 5V line on one of the slaves. That slave will then pull the A4 and A5 lines to GND. My pullups doesn't do enough to pull it back. How can I circumvent this behavior?

My ideas range from using some kind of solid state "relay"/analog multiplexer to ensure the I2C bus is electronically disconnected from the Arduino when powered down, to using some opto-decoupler. I have not used such methods before and perhaps there are better ways of doing this. I'd prefer not to add extra hardware unless I have to. By the way, I don't necessarily need to have bidirectional communication over the bus. I only need the master to broadcast messages to all slaves at once.

Comment: GPIO protection diodes. Instead of powering down, you need to keep power applied, but put the slave device(s) into a low-power state.

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate! Spot on. The unidirectional buffers as referred there would probably sort my problem out.

Comment: Not really. See the comment I left on the answer there.

Comment: Just came to the same conclusion the hard way. :)